quit mode push notifaction
CASES : 
android 11 or less version than that debug and production and all states - quit, foreground , background sab main push notification aata hai us par tap karke internal screen pe chale jate hain -
lakin android 12 or greater in debug and production mode states - foreground , background main push notification aata hai us par tap karke internal screen pe chale jate hain - jab baat aati hai quit mode me to notification home page ko open kr ke chod deta h internal screen pr nahi jata h. aisa kyu ho raha h , mai react native ka project use kr raha hu or messaging ke liye firebase messaging use kr raha hu
android 12 and greater version problem

This site is English only, which means you would have to translate your question, if you may desire an answer.
